# How to specify root url for Ember?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js

I am trying to change the url path for the api end-point as the ember app is connecting to an external api.

Locally my ember app is at localhost, and the api is at localhost:3000.

If I try the following:

```
DS.RESTAdapter.reopen
  namespace: "api"
  url: "http://localhost:3003"
```

And I click on a linkTo helper I get the following error:

```
No route matches [GET] "/api/tasks
```

How do I get it to bypass the Rails provided route on localhost:3000 to go straight to the api server? So it should request `localhost:3003/api/tasks` instead of `localhost:3000/api/tasks`

Comment: I think your problem is in routes.rb, because the server receives the request, but No route matches. Can you show your rails router configuration?

Comment: I haven't set up the rails router at all besides `  root to: 'application#index'`

Comment: Please give a look in my answer, and give me know if it solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem isn't related to ember routing, but the rails routing. You need to use the `namespace` to setup a namespace for your resources in the `routes.rb`. Like the following:

```
namespace :api do
  resources :tasks
end
```

I hope it helps

Comment: But ember should bypass rails routes? My point is that I have to pull it in from an external app, not localhost.

Answer (score 0):

You should be setting the `host`, not `url` property on `RESTAdapter`. For example:

```
DS.RESTAdapter.reopen
  namespace: "api"
  host: "http://localhost:3003"
```

See [API reference](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTAdapter.html#toc_host-customization).